# How to make menus in my navigation drawer clickable to open new activities

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, android-manifest, navigation-drawer

There are some declarations that we have to make in the manifest file. I tried doing that but kept getting some errors. My app runs normally, but on the selection of the menu item, my app stops.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sachinsharma.nav">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also I know that I will have to use the Intent methods to start my new activity, which again I did but it keeps having the same problem.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sachinsharma.nav
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import static android.R.attr.value;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int id){

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.nav_dashboard:
                fragment = new FragDashboard();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_attendance:
                fragment = new FragAttendance();
                break;
//            case R.id.nav_homework:
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_exams:
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_fee:
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_notifications:
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_tracking:
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_profile:
//                break;
        }

        if(fragment != null){

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            ft.commit();

            //this transaction does not replace layouts completely, it just overlaps and the rest
            //of content_main layout can still be seen
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        displaySelectedScreen(id);

        return true;
    }
}
```

NewActivity.java

```
package com.example.sachinsharma.nav;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

/**
 * Created by sachinsharma on 4/4/17.
 */

public class NewActivity extends MainActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }
}
```

The following are the menu items in my drawer.

action_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="Dashboard" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_attendance"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_watch_later_black_24dp"
        android:title="Attendance" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_homework"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_announcement_black_24dp"
        android:title="Homework" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_exams"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_assignment_black_24dp"
        android:title="Exams" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_fee"
        android:icon="@drawable/rupee"
        android:title="Fee" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_notifications_active_black_24dp"
        android:title="Notifications" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tracking"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_directions_bus_black_24dp"
        android:title="Tracking" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
        android:title="Profile" />


</menu>
```

Comment: Kindly, help me out on this. As I am new to android.

Comment: Can you please post error logs?

Comment: I would suggest using fragments and switching them out if you are using a NavigationDrawer. Here's a link for reference: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you should use fragments. What you are doing is you are opening another activity which is not having the navigation drawer and `the fact is you can have only one navigation drawer per activity but multiple fragments per activity and not multiple activities per activity`.

Try using fragments and everything will work fine also having lots of activities in an app makes it laggy and users will most probably remove your app.

Anything more let me know and, `for the code just create new project in android studio and select navigation drawer activity over there and create your project after that read the code you will get the concept of fragments`.

Best of Luck!

Comment: I updated my code by using fragments, but now the layout for the menu is over the existing layout and that too not completely. Please check the MainActivity.java code. 
If you need any more detail please ask.

Comment: I updated my code by using fragments, but now the layout for the menu is over the existing layout and that too not completely.
Please check MainActivity.java, nav_dashboard.xml has a textview with text dashboard, which keeps appearing along with the elements of the launcher activity instead of replacing them completely.

Comment: I think you did not create a demo project with navigation. The thing is in your mainactivity xml file there will be content xml file which will be included which takes care of replacing different fragments

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare `NewActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Don't forget to apply theme `AppTheme.NoActionBar` for `NewActivity`.

**Update your `AndroidMenifest.xml` as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sachinsharma.nav">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".NewActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I tried to do this, but my app keeps crashing on menu selection. Any idea why it might be happening?